# Matching a string that does not contain certain word... without lookaround

Tags: regex

I would like to use (pure) regex to match strings that do not contain the word `word`.

However, I would **not** like to use **lookaround**, **balancing groups**, or that kind of stuff.

If it is impossible, then can we match strings that do not **start** with `word` instead?

---

#### Examples

- `word` should **not** match.
- `wor` **should** match.
- `wore` **should** match.

Comment: Try something like wor[^d]?

Comment: Lookaround was added because plain regexes can't handle what you're trying to do.

Comment: Then just match strings that do not **start** with `word`, as stated in the question.

Comment: I would also appreciate it if you could prove that (pure) regex cannot do that.

Comment: @SMA: but it should match 'this' and 'that' too — they don't contain 'word'.

Comment: Let's start with what you mean by 'pure regex'.  Which dialect do you consider to be pure enough to use?  POSIX BRE?  ERE?  PCRE except for lookarounds?

Comment: You know, `^a+a*a?(?:ab|cd)$`

Comment: With the non-matching group there, your example looks like PCRE, which *does* support lookarounds.

Comment: You might find useful information at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html which says, in part: _Negative lookahead is indispensable if you want to match something not followed by something else. When explaining character classes, this tutorial explained why you cannot use a negated character class to match a 'q' not followed by a 'u'. Negative lookahead provides the solution: `q(?!u)`._  (And 'character classes' was a link to a tutorial.)

Comment: Or without the non-capturing group, pretty close to pre-POSIX `egrep`, i.e. proto-ERE.

Comment: As @tripleee mentioned (and deleted his post), you can do the permutations `\b(?:[^w]|wor(?:$|[^d])|wo(?:$|[^r])|w(?:$|[^o]))+` however, it still needs some anchor or _boundary_ to stop it from matching w`ord` if you get my drift..

Answer (score 2):

use this pattern

```
^.*\bword\b.*$|(.+)
```

match strings that has word first, then match and capture strings that don't
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/365)

---

Depending on your engine, you could use this pattern

```
^.*\bword\b.*$(*SKIP)(*F)|(.+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/366)

Comment: Can I... not... match those?

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion if you can use this technique, but it's not applicable everywhere.

Comment: @KennyLau, updated answer above

Comment: @tripleee, please give an example!

Comment: If your task is to find all non-matching lines in an editor which only provides line-oriented search, for example, the fact that you don't *capture* the matching lines does nothing to help you avoid matching them, one by one.

Comment: @tripleee, look at updated answer!

Comment: I saw that, but I'm guessing those facilities aren't allowed if even lookaheads are ruled out. The OP should definitely have clarified the requirements, ideally already in the original question.